# php pdostament fetch issue

Tags: php, pdo

I have a database which has two record for testing purposes... 
database columns(user_id, username, password and role)....

I am using PHP PDO to communicate with database i have created a class file that extends PDO which is below

```
<?php
    require_once('constants.php');
    class PDOConfig extends PDO{

        private $real_escape_string;
        private $mageic_quote_active;


        public function __construct(){
            $dsn = DBENGINE .':dbname='. DBNAME.";host=".DBHOST; 
            parent::__construct($dsn, DBUSER, DBPW);
            $mageic_quote_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
            $real_escape_string = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string");
        }


        public function escapeValue($value){
            //PHP >= 4.3.0 or greater
            if($this->real_escape_string){
                if($this->mageic_quote_active){
                    //if new version exists turn magic quotes off
                    $value = stripslashes($value);
                }
                $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            }
            return $value;
        }

    }//end of class

    $connection = new PDOConfig();
    $database =& $connection;
```

i am using this file on my login page which has the following code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Sign In</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/singin-form.css">

        <?php require_once('includes/PDOConfig-class.php'); ?>
        <?php //require_once('includes/utility-functions.php'); ?>
        <?php
            $errors = "";
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                $username = trim($_POST['username']);
                $password = trim($_POST['password']);

                if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = '" . $database->escapeValue($username) . "'";
                    $prestmt = $database->prepare($sql);
                    $prestmt->execute();
                    $result = $prestmt->fetch($database::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    //print_r($result);
                    echo $result['role'];


                    echo "<br /> Query :  " . $sql;
                }
                //echo '<div class="alert alert-error">something wrong<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>';
            }

        ?>


    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <form class="form-signin" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                <h2>Please sign in</h2>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="input-block-level" placeholder="User Name" />
                <input type="password" name="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" />
                <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

### but i dont see anything on my page beside that query that i print... although there there is data there in the database...

another thing when i try to  "FETCH_OBJ" use I get the following error

```
trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\testPHP\login.php on line 30
```

the code that generate above error is below

```
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = '" . $database->escapeValue($username) . "'";
    $prestmt = $database->prepare($sql);
    $prestmt->execute();
    $result = $prestmt->fetch($database::FETCH_OBJ);
    echo $result->role;
}
```

please help as i have never used PHP PDO and not very good in php... thanks for you time

Comment: Just a note, but even though you escape the username, etc when putting it into the query, you are not utilizing the security that prepared statements (thats what prepare() creates) offers you. You should have something like ... WHERE user_name=:username... and then your execute() would take an array with ':username' => $username in it

Comment: a side note: you have to **get rid** of ALL stuff contains words 'escape' and 'magic'. I mean completely

Comment: another note. Do not indent PHP code at the same level with HTML. It makes your code a real mess. Always start PHP from the very left.

Comment: thanks very much both of you @Los Frijoles and "Your Common Sense" .... that was really helpful... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) contains everything you need

- Connect to db the way described there (to make PDO to inform you on errors)
- Assign variables to the query the way described there (to make your query safe and sensible)
- Get rid of your PDOConfig as it's totally useless. you need only constructor from there , so, you can just put constructor code itself into PDOConfig-class.php

Then run your code and see what is going wrong